# matching multiple values using one regex?

Tags: c#, regex

i am having this regex to match on this given data. it must match every reference name(include) and also it should match other values if its given there. 
**source data ..**

```
<Reference Include="Interop.ERMSPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b5fdd3f42e76a9c0, processorArchitecture=MSIL">        <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Epiplex500\epiplex\Bin\SharedInterop.ERMSPlugin.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="LicenseProcessing">
 <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Epiplex500\epiplex\Bin\Shared\LicenseProcessing.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Snapshot">
      <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Epiplex500\epiplex\Bin\Shared\Snapshot.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
```

i am using this regex.

```
<Reference Include="(?:([^,|"]+?)[,|"]|[\s\S]*?Version=([^,]+?),[\s\S]*?PublicKeyToken=([^,|"]+)\S([^">]+?)[\s\S]*?<HintPath>([\s\S]*?)<\/HintPath>[\s\S]*?)
```

i need version, public key, and path along with given name.
its matching only reference name others are ignored. 
anyone plz help me out here.

thanks

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). Seriously, regex is absolutely, positively, a wrong tool for the task.

Comment: Why not just parse the xml?..

Comment: This is some msbuild script right?

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft.Build` and use the [`Project`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) class to parse a .csproj file. It's that simple.

Comment: yes its csproj file. its working but it gives only reference name. i need all info.and i have to use regex only.

Comment: Why would you have to use regex only? Use the proper tools for the job.

Comment: @Harry007 You can't. Properties in `Include` attribute may follow in any order. You can extract entire attribute, and then try parse it with `Regex.Matches` method, it can work.

Comment: If you think you really need to do it with a regex, you can try `(?<=<Reference Include="[^"]*?)(?:Version|PublicKeyToken)=(?<txt>[\p{Zs}\w\p{P}]+)(?=, )|(?<=<Reference Include=".*?<HintPath>)(?<path>[^<]*?)(?=<\/HintPath>[\s\S]*?)` that returns several matches (I doubt you can obtain everything in capture groups only because of what Mark Shevchenko wrote about), but again, it is really strange that you refuse from using regular XML parser for such a task.

Comment: i m new to c#. i don't know how to do this using xml parser.thats why i used regex.

Comment: can any one help me out using xml parser.

Comment: @Harry007 do **NOT** use a XML parser, use the [`Project`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx) class instead, it's designed to parse MSBuild files and it's much easier to use. I don't have time right now but I'll write an answer later if no-one does it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the `Microsoft.Build` and still using regular expressions:

Add the reference by right-clicking the *[Solution]* > **Add References...**, selecting **Assemblies** > **Framework** > `Microsoft.Build` and then hitting **OK**.

And here is the code itself (EDIT: now, it should process all Reference nodes):

```
var project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"FILE_PATH.csproj");
var references = project.Items.Where(p => p.ItemType == "Reference").Select(p => p);
foreach (var reference in references)
{
      var ReferenceName = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"^[\w\.]+(?=,\p{Zs}|$)", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
      var version = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"(?s:(?<=Version=)([\d\.]+))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
      var keyToken = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"(?s:(?<=PublicKeyToken=)([\w\-]+))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
      var hintpath = reference.GetMetadata("HintPath") != null ? reference.GetMetadata("HintPath").EvaluatedValue : string.Empty;
}
```

EDIT2: In case there are problems with matching the values in the Inlcude attribute, you can also use these regexes that are just matching all non-space characters before a "comma+space" or a line end:

```
var ReferenceName = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"^[^\p{Zs}]+(?=,\p{Zs}|$)", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
var version = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"(?s:(?<=Version=)([^\p{Zs}]+(?=,\p{Zs}|$)))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
var keyToken = Regex.Match(reference.EvaluatedInclude, @"(?s:(?<=PublicKeyToken=)([^\p{Zs}]+(?=,\p{Zs}|$)))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant).Value;
```

Comment: To simplify, I'd change `project.Items.Where(p => p.ItemType == "Reference").Select(p => p)` to `project.GetItems("Reference")` and `^[\w\.]+(?=,\p{Zs}|$)` to `^[^,]+` but otherwise this looks good.

Comment: sorry for that. i will definitely mark when i m above 15.